# How to install tor meek TP on openwrt flashed router?

Tags: pluggable-transports, meek

I was trying to find out a way to install tor meek on OpenWRT. Can someone tell me how to cross compile the meek client with OpenWRT?

Answer (score 1):

You can't cross-compile using OS, you need a [cross-compiling environment](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware.sdk) and you're also required to cross-compile [Go language from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source). Also take a close look at special [Go fork for OpenWRT](https://github.com/GeertJohan/openwrt-go/issues/2)

After that make a [Meek source compiled](https://github.com/arlolra/meek) =)

Answer (score 1):

`Meek` is written in Go. It has pretty reasonable cross-platform compilation options (compared to some languages).

First, you don't only cross-compile based on the operating system, you cross-compile based on the architecture *and* operating system. You need to know what architecture your OpenWRT router is running on. Go supports quite a wide variety of options and since Golang 1.5 cross-compiling has been a lot easier.

https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment

> Choices for $GOOS are darwin (Mac OS X 10.7 and above and iOS), dragonfly, freebsd, linux, netbsd, openbsd, plan9, solaris and windows. Choices for $GOARCH are amd64 (64-bit x86, the most mature port), 386 (32-bit x86), arm (32-bit ARM), arm64 (64-bit ARM), ppc64le (PowerPC 64-bit, little-endian), ppc64 (PowerPC 64-bit, big-endian), mips64le (MIPS 64-bit, little-endian), and mips64 (MIPS 64-bit, big-endian).

Then, to build a copy of the `meek-client`, lets say for Linux on ARM64 you'd run a series of commands like:

```
export GOPATH=`mktemp -d`
export GOARCH=arm64
export GOOS=linux
go get -u git.torproject.org/pluggable-transports/meek.git/meek-client
```

and this should result in a copy of `meek-client` built for linux on arm64 in the `$GOPATH/bin/linux_arm64/` folder:

```
$ file $GOPATH/bin/linux_arm64/meek-client
/tmp/tmp.kovJoNMmiL/bin/linux_arm64/meek-client: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

Then your OpenWRT's Tor then needs to be configured to use meek, assuming you installed the `meek-client` you built before at `/usr/local/bin/meek-client` and you wanted to use the google domain front you'd add some lines to your torrc like these

```
ClientTransportPlugin meek exec /usr/local/bin/meek-client --url=https://meek-reflect.appspot.com/ --front=https://www.google.com/
UseBridges 1
Bridge meek 0.0.2.0:1
```